# Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #100) (#100) targeting[geo_locations][zips][key] must be a json object

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been trying to understand what this error is caused by.

I'm creating a ad campaign, and so far, the only problem seems to be that facebook requires the targeting field to be a JSON object. Strange thing is, I thought I already gave it a JSON object.

I'm using the facebooksdk.net and newtonsoft json.

Snip:

```
client.post("/v2.5/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adsets", new {
  ..., 
  targeting = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    geo_locations = new {
      zips = new {
        key = "US:10001"
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the question is answered. I needed to use a combination of implicitly typed local variables and implicitly typed arrays.